# Hide Clock from Status bar

Tags: iphone, ipad

How to hide only Clock from Status bar.

is this possible ?

anyone have a idea how can i do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask *why* would you want to hide just the time in the status bar? It's best not to try to do non-standard things unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: hello, I want to display in Lable in my screen with large size, so no need to display to clock on Status bar.

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's possible but a little bit tricky, since the status bar is in another window. You might want to have a look at the implementation of [MTStatusBarOverlay](https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay).

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible using the official iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add a UIView that would cover up the time in the status bar to hide it.

Comment: Not possible unfortunately, you can't position a UIView over the status bar.